Using a Schengen Visa for a Different Country and Future Visa Applications
I currently hold an Austrian Schengen visa. Originally, I planned to visit Austria for an organized event, but that event has already passed because the processing time of the visa took too long, and I no longer have a specific reason to go to Austria.
Instead, I’m thinking of taking advantage of my visa to explore either Spain or France. However, I’m concerned about whether this might cause any issues when I apply for a France visa soon.
Has anyone had experience with this? Will using my Austrian visa to visit Spain or France instead of Austria create any trouble for me in future Schengen visa applications, particularly when I apply for a France visa? Or it can cause trouble only when applying again to Austria?
Thanks in advance for your advice!

You change destination and reason of travel, both are red flags (at entry and for next Schengen visa), so maybe further delays. is it your first Schengen visa? -- my recommendation: visit Austria

no, it's the third Schengen visa, but previous visas were given from another country not Austria

Schengen is enough: all immigration offices should have information of other Schengen visa. if you already had two Schengen visa, it helps: less probability they (France, etc.) get an idea you are "visa shopping" (trying to find the easiest embassy)


Will using my Austrian visa to visit Spain or France instead of Austria create any trouble for me in future Schengen visa applications, particularly when I apply for a France visa? Or it can cause trouble only when applying again to Austria?

It's worse than you think.  If you use that visa to visit Spain or France, you run the risk of being refused admission to the Schengen area, having the visa cancelled or revoked, and being sent home.  This could result in a fine or a temporary ban from traveling to the Schengen area.
In theory, this could even happen if you use the visa to travel as a tourist to Austria, because one of the criteria for revoking a visa is that the conditions for issuing it no longer prevail.  I suspect that this is less likely, but I am not certain.
The safest course of action is probably to plan a tourist visit to Austria.  If you visit other Schengen countries during this trip, ensure that you spend more time in Austria than in any other country.  Then write the consulate to inform them of your change in plans and of the reason (i.e. because the visa was approved too late for you to use it for the original purpose), and ask them whether you should use the existing visa or apply for a new one.
If they tell you that you can use the existing visa, take copies of your letter and theirs with you in case you are challenged at the border.
If they tell you to apply for a new visa, you can either do that or cancel your trip to Austria, plan your trip to Spain or France, and apply for a new visa from the appropriate consulate.
Now it is certainly within the spirit of the Schengen codes to allow you to use the original visa for a trip to Spain or France in these circumstances, but the border officers of various Schengen countries are variably sensitive to the possibility of travelers abusing the rules, and it is not difficult to find stories online of people being sent back for trips that don't match their visa applications in one way or another.  It's certainly not strictly against the rules to do what you're proposing, but it's not obvious that it's definitely allowed, and in any event you won't have a good opportunity to make your case.
Border officers can generally send you back even if they're wrong.  It's better to play it safe.

Thank you for your detailed answer, what about cancelling the trip and not using the visa at all until it's expired, is this ok and safe ?

Yes, not using the visa is safe, it is the most safe of all options

@HamzaAZIZ yes, not using the visa should be safe, especially since you have a good reason for not doing so.

But how they will know the reason ? If I apply to France next time, should I mention it on an invitation letter ?

Another option is to apply again for a French (or Spanish) visa and request that the Austrian visa be revolked, since you could not use it for the intended purpose.

@MarkJohnson the Austria visa will end soon, before I can manage to get appointments and collect documents for the France or spanish VISA
